# RF JsonRpcProxy "is neither a getter nor a setter"

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, json-rpc

I'm getting `is neither a getter nor a setter` when gwt is compiling my `@JsonRpcProxy` annotated `ValueProxy` interfaces.

I have those methods implemented with an Autobean `Category` but seems that `RquestFactoryGenerator` can't handle them:

> [ERROR] [modules] The method public abstract client.beans.ExpenseFreeBase findExpenseFreeBaseAssignedForThisDate(java.util.Date date) is neither a getter nor a setter

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that simply is not supported: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/rebind/model/RequestFactoryModel.java#329

Feel free to open a request-enhancement (as I couldn't find an existing one) at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list and see how the GWT team feels about it.

Comment: Thanks again Thomas. I hope JsonRpc support improves from experimental.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7378&thanks=7378&ts=1337268575

Comment: Thomas, reading the code it seems that the no-getter-setter methods aren't supported in any RF-Proxy actually. Is not related to be an JsonRpcProxy. I'm right?

Comment: It seems that is ignoring methods for EntityProxy. Why not for ValueProxy? http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/rebind/model/RequestFactoryModel.java#321

Comment: I believe the code simply hadn't been updated when ValueProxies were introduced, but it works the same for all proxies; and you're right it also works the same here whether using JSON-RPC or not.